# Rails remote: true doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action/view called `one` (one.html.haml). In `one`, I have a remote form:

```
= form_tag("two", remote: true) do
  = email_field_tag "email"
```

I have this route to handle the submit:

```
post '/two' => 'home#two'
```

On desktop, the remote property works just fine. Upon submit, my JavaScript is executed.

On iOS strangely, when I do the same submit, it doesn't trigger the JavaScript, but instead loads `/two` as a GET request (which means it navigates to that page).

Any idea why it would work on desktop web but not mobile web?

Comment: Are you able to debug it in Safari? https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: Just as @BrianKung mentioned, the best way to debug this is through Web Inspector on your computer, connected to a device or simulator. Btw, did you make sure that JavaScript is enabled on your iOS device? If so, I'm curious if adding `method: :post` to your `form_tag` helps.

Comment: Is this inside safari or a custom ios app?

Comment: It's inside Safari. Not sure what debugging I would do? It just redirects the page. `method: :post` didn't make a difference.